# Android Alert Dialog Checkbox Text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components, material-components-android

[image]I have a MaterialAlertDialogBuilder, I am passing to it the following ContextThemeWrapper:

```
<style name="MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">?customfrontcolour</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">?customtextcolor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">?customtextcolor</item>
</style>
```

I can't figure out how to change the color of the of the text next to checkbox ( "Beirut" ).

I tried all adding all the following to my `MyThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog:`

```
"textColorAlertDialogListItem"
"android:textColor"
"android:textColorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to define a custom style for the Dialog using the **`android:checkedTextViewStyle`** attribute:

```
  <style name="dialogCheckedStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle" ns2:ignore="NewApi">@style/myCheckedTextView</item>
  </style>
```

Then define:

```
  <style name="myCheckedTextView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CheckedTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Then just show the dialog with:

```
  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,
      R.style.dialogCheckedStyle)
      .setMultiChoiceItems(....)
      //...
      .show();
```

[image]

The default color is defined by this selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/material_emphasis_medium" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is now changing

Comment: @PierreKhoury what does it mean *it is now changing*?

Comment: sry I meant it is not* working. I replicated your code and nothing changed. Whatever I tried doing the text next to the checkboxes is always black.

Comment: @PierreKhoury Which version are you using? Just tried it and it works with 1.1.0-beta02 and 1.2.0-alpha01

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I am using 1.2.0-alpha01. Anyway I'll do some more testing and I'll report back if I find the problem. thanks

Comment: after endless searching I found the answer. I had to change the attribute colorOnSurface to change the color that is next to the checkboxes.

Comment: @PierreKhoury The default selector used by `android:checkedTextViewStyle` is `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="@dimen/material_emphasis_medium" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/></selector>`. You can change the attribute `colorOnSurface` at app theme level or you can simply override this value in the component.